# How to preserve colorspace in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-quality, transcoding, colorspace, h265

I have a `x264` video with `yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m)` color space and i want to convert this video to `x265` and reduce its file size. I have used this command `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 20 output.mp4` but the video got darker and when i runned ffprobe i saw the colorspace changed to `yuvj420p(pc, progressive)` How can i preserve color space while transcoding?

Answer (score 4):

This command preserved the colorspace and also video didnt get darker after transcoding

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -color_primaries smpte170m -color_trc smpte170m -colorspace smpte170m -r 25 -crf 18 output.mp4
```

source: https://kdenlive.org/en/project/color-hell-ffmpeg-transcoding-and-preserving-bt-601/

more about colorspace: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/colorspace